# Как определить, в какой кодировке заливать данные в csv (открытие через excel)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Есть код:

```
import csv 
parsing_data = [{'phrase': 'пс4', 'num': '90152', 'link': '/#!/?words=%D0%BF%D1%814'}] 
output_file = open("pr.csv", "w") 
wrtr = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=["phrase", "num", "link"]) 
wrtr.writerow(parsing_data)
```

Результат кода в excel:

> РїСЃ4 90152 /#!/?words=%D0%BF%D1%814

Данные с файла считываются нормально, как и должны быть. Как я понял проблема в кодировке. Как узнать в какой кодировке открывает эти данные excel? Пробовал напрямую перекодировать phrase (посредством str.encode('utf-8')) - все равно заливает мусор. Может быть, я что-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 2):

[Excel позволяет при импорте данных указать их кодировку](https://superuser.com/q/280603/13868):

```
"Data" -> "Get External Data" -> "Import Text File"
```

Поэтому сохраняйте данные в любой кодировке по вашему выбору. utf-8 поддерживает произвольные Unicode символы, поэтому если у вас нет особых предпочтений, то можно её по умолчанию использовать.

Кодировка результата определяется с помощью `encoding` параметра для `open()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

with open('pr.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=["phrase", "num", "link"])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(parsing_data)
```

Обратите внимание: `writerows()`, а не `writerow()`. Также следует `newline=''` использовать с файлами, передаваемыми в csv модуль (чтобы окончания строк не портились).

Comment: Пробовал, но открывая файл в exel - выводит неправильную кодировку. Открывая файл в  encoding='cp1251'  все работает.

Comment: @Тимур смысл ответа, что вы вы а не excel задаёте кодировку. То есть данные лежат на диске в какой-то конкретной кодировке (зависит кто эти данные писал—это может быть **что угодно**). Сам csv файл не содержит указания кодировки явного, поэтому вы должны по другим каналам узнать (спросите того кто пишет эти файлы). При загрузке файла в excel вы явно указываете эту кодировку. Если вы знаете, что файл сохранен в cp1251, тогда вы Excel и говорите, что файл сохранён именно в этой кодировке. Хотя если не указать, то на русской Винде он может эту кодировку по умолчанию использовать—точно не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам поможет chardet. Может определить кодировку по строке.
[Доки](http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
>>> import urllib
>>> rawdata = urllib.urlopen('http://yahoo.co.jp/').read()
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(rawdata)
{'encoding': 'EUC-JP', 'confidence': 0.99}
```

Comment: Chardet может гадать, но точно  он не может ответ кроме специальных случаев дать.